# C++: how can I overload a function so that it can take any functor, including pointer to member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

In order to broaden my understanding of C++11, I'm experimenting with writing functional helpers and seeing if I can make calling them less verbose. Right now I'm trying to write a `some` function that returns true if any item in a collection passes a test. I want it to work with any collection type, be able to take any callable, and not require template arguments.

Essentially, I want it to work such that the following code will compile:

```
// insert declaration of some here
#include <list>
#include <functional>

class Foo {
public:
    bool check() const { return true; };
};

class DerivedFooList : public std::list<Foo> {
public:
    DerivedFooList(std::initializer_list<Foo> args) : std::list<Foo>(args) {};
};

class DerivedFooPtrList : public std::list<Foo *> {
public:
    DerivedFooPtrList(std::initializer_list<Foo *> args) : std::list<Foo *>(args) {};
};

bool intCheck(int a) { return a == 1; }
bool fooCheck(const Foo &a) { return a.check(); }
bool fooPtrCheck(const Foo *a) { return a->check(); }

int main()
{
    Foo a, b, c;
    std::list<int> intList = {1, 2, 3};
    std::list<Foo> fooList = {a, b, c};
    std::list<Foo *> fooPtrList = {&a, &b, &c};
    DerivedFooList derivedFooList = {a, b, c};
    DerivedFooPtrList derivedFooPtrList = {&a, &b, &c};

    auto localIntCheck = [] (int a) { return a == 1; };
    auto localFooCheck = [] (const Foo &a) { return a.check(); };
    auto localFooPtrCheck = [] (const Foo *a) { return a->check(); };

    some(intList, [] (int a) { return a == 1; });
    some(intList, &intCheck);
    some(intList, localIntCheck);

    some(fooList, [] (const Foo &a) { return a.check(); });
    some(fooList, &fooCheck);
    some(fooList, localFooCheck);
    some(fooList, &Foo::check);

    some(fooPtrList, [] (const Foo *a) { return a->check(); });
    some(fooPtrList, &fooPtrCheck);
    some(fooPtrList, localFooPtrCheck);
    some(fooPtrList, &Foo::check);

    some(derivedFooList, [] (const Foo &a) { return a.check(); });
    some(derivedFooList, &fooCheck);
    some(derivedFooList, localFooCheck);
    some(derivedFooList, &Foo::check);

    some(derivedFooPtrList, [] (const Foo *a) { return a->check(); });
    some(derivedFooPtrList, &fooPtrCheck);
    some(derivedFooPtrList, localFooPtrCheck);
    some(derivedFooPtrList, &Foo::check);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if the value type of the collection is an object or object pointer, I want to be able to pass a pointer to a member function as the second argument to `some`. And that's where things get hairy.

My first attempt was to implement it like this:

```
template <class T, class F>
bool some(const T &list, F &&func)
{
    for(auto item : list) {
        if (func(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <template<class, class> class T, class U, class V, class W>
bool some(const T<U, V> &list, bool (W::*func)() const)
{
    return some(list, [=](U const &t){ return (t.*func)(); });
}

template <template<class, class> class T, class U, class V, class W>
bool some(const T<U *, V> &list, bool (W::*func)() const)
{
    return some(list, [=](U const *t){ return (t->*func)(); });
}
```

...but it doesn't work if the collection is not an STL collection, or at least one that takes two template arguments. In my example, using `DerivedFooList` or `DerivedFooPtrList` won't work.

My second attempt looked like this:

```
template <class T, class F>
bool some(const T &list, F &&func)
{
    for(auto item : list) {
        if (func(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <class T, class U>
bool some(const T &list, bool (U::*func)() const)
{
    return some(list, [=](U const &t) { return (t.*func)(); });
}
```

That works with `DerivedFooList` now, but doesn't work with `std::list<Foo *>` or `DerivedFooPtrList`.

My third attempt was this:

```
template <class T, class F>
bool some(const T &list, F &&func)
{
    for(auto item : list) {
        if (func(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <class T, class U>
bool some(typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type const &list, bool (U::*func)() const)
{
    return some(list, [=](U const &t) { return (t.*func)(); });
}

template <class T, class U>
bool some(typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type const &list, bool (U::*func)() const)
{
    return some(list, [=](U const *t) { return (t->*func)(); });
}
```

Ignoring for the time being that this would only work with collections that have a member named `value_type`, it still doesn't allow my above example to compile. I think (but am not 100% sure) the reason is that it can't deduce T for the second two versions of `some` for the cases where I want it to be used.

I've tried very hard to see if there's a way to get what I want out of C++11, and I suspect that there is, but I can't figure it out. Is what I want possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Only up to C++11? How about C++17?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use C++17 for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class R, class F>
bool some( R const& r, F&& f ) {
  for(auto&& x:r)
    if (std::ref(f)(decltype(x)(x)))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

`std::ref` overloads `()` to do the `INVOKE` concept, which in C++17 can be accessed directly via `std::invoke`.  Your requirements seem to line up with the `INVOKE` concept.

`decltype(x)(x)` is equivalent to a `std::forward` expression if `x` is a deduced `auto&&` variable.  Read it as "treat `x` as if it was the type it was declared as".  Note that if `x` is an `auto` value, it copies, unlike `forward`.

`INVOKE( pmf, ptr )` and `INVOKE( pmf, ref )` both work.  So no need to do fancy stuff in the overload.

Comment: This does the trick! Best of all I no longer need to overload any of the functions I'm writing. Can you help me understand why it's necessary to use `decltype(x)(x)`? What sort of thing could go wrong if I exclude it?

Comment: @guy if `r` is an input iterator range of `T`, `x` would be an lvalue while `ddeclt6pe(x)(x)` is an rvalue.  And binding to an lvalue is nonsense, inefficient, and generally wrong.  For most conventional containers, no difference.  But no harm to.

Comment: Just use `const` for clarity and efficiency. Avoid too subtle things and dark corners of the language.